# Eavesdropping experiment with private key

Tags: public-key, protocol-design

I am extremely new to cryptography, still trying to learn basics. I got stuck in the following example of an eavesdropping experiment with a private key.

$$\begin{array} {|r|r r r|r|}
\hline
C & & & & A \\
\hline
k & \leftarrow & Gen(1^{n}) & & \ \\
b & \leftarrow & {0, 1} & \leftarrow [m_0,m_1] \leftarrow & input 1^{n} \\
c & \leftarrow & Enck (m_b) & \rightarrow [c] \rightarrow & output b_0 \\
\hline
\end{array}$$

$A$ succeeds, if $b = b_0$.

Could someone give a basic of what is going on here and point to some resources where I can get the hang of these things?

Comment: Well, what exactly do you not understand? If you want it in words: the adversary chooses two messages, and then obtains one of those two messages in encrypted form. The adversary then must guess which of the two messages was encrypted.

Comment: Thank you very much fkraiem. First, I didn't understand the 1^n function used as input as well as used to generate keys. Is  it just a simple example or a cenvention used to show?
Also, what I understood is that this is a model used to test how effective the security is.So when the Adversary received the encrypted message, does it try to get the plain text m0 or m1 back. And after that, can it derive the private key?

Comment: The $1^n$ input is to allow the algorithm to run in time polynomial in $n$, because the algorithm runs in time polynomial to the length of its input. No, the adversary is not required to "decrypt" the ciphertext it obtains (whatever you could mean by that), only to tell whether it is $m_0$ or $m_1$, using whatever strategy it wishes.

Comment: @AnkurBhatia : I hope the answer below will address your original question and the one in the comments. As for references, depending on your background, these [lecture notes](https://wiki.cc.gatech.edu/theory/index.php/CS_8803TFC_-_Theoretical_Foundations_of_Cryptography,_Spring_2010) may help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a simple/laymans explanation of what the example is (most likely) about:

Suppose you are given a new ciphering scheme (set of encryption and decryption algorithms) and you need to find out if it is secure. In cryptography, the security can be analyzed by issuing a challenge to the eavesdropper or adversary $A$. If the adversary wins the challenge, the cipher is insecure and vice-versa. This exercise consists of the following steps:

1. The challenger $C$ (on the left in your figure) generates a random key $k$ of appropriate length: a randomly-generated $n$ bit key would mathematically be represented as $k \leftarrow Gen[1^n]$ or $k \leftarrow \{0,1\}^n$ (I find the latter representation clearer).
2. The adversary $A$ (on the right in your figure) inputs two messages $m_0$ and $m_1$ to the challenger. Assuming these are $n$ bit messages, one can represent them as $\{0,1\}^n$ too.
3. The challenger encrypts *only* one of these messages $c \leftarrow Enck(k,m)$ with $m$ = $m_0$ or $m_1$. (Think of the challenger tossing a coin; if he gets heads/tails, he encrypts $m_0/m_1$). In the figure, this operation is represented as $c \leftarrow Enck(k,m_b)$ which then depends on the value of a single bit $b$.
4. The ciphertext $c$ is handed to the adversary who analyzes it with all possible resources he/she possesses (remember though that they don't know the key) and at the end of the analysis, outputs a bit $b_0$.
5. If $b_0 = b$, the adversary has won the challenge.

Remember the last line is to be interpreted in a statistical sense, i.e., if the challenger-adversary game is played $2N$ times, $b_0 = b$ must be true for $>N$ times.

Comment: Thank you very much jayann for this excellent explaination. I would really appreciate if you could also point me to some resources so that I can understand these basics clearly. I have a very good understanding of network protocols. Want to start learning the security side of it.